# ¿Por qué Codeblocks 16.03 falla al inicio del debug de proyectos C++ en Linux Mint 19.3?

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks, gcc, depuración

Tengo un problema con Codeblocks en Linux, consiste en que cuándo intento hacer build and run a un proyecto, se cuelga al inicio del debug. El log me arroja el siguiente mensaje:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in Areas (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++-8  -o bin/Debug/Areas obj/Debug/main.o   
execvp(./home/pelu/Fundamentos, de, , g++-8  -o bin/Debug/Areas obj/Debug/main.o) failed with error 2!
Process terminated with status -1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Si elijo "No" cuándo me pregunta "No has hecho build a tu proyecto aún. ¿Quieres hacerlo ahora?", en consola me dice que no ha encontrado el archivo en el directorio /bin/Debug, y me da el siguiente error `Process returned 127 (0x27f)`. Buscando en google he averiguado que el error 127 tiene que ver con fallos en el path o bien con errores ortográficos (typo),  segundo es descartable pues no me funciona el debug ni del proyecto de ejemplo HelloWorld.

Decir también que sé que las rutas con espacios en blanco generan problemas. No entiendo por qué en el log aparece una carpeta con espacios en blanco (Fundamentos de..), pues los archivos están en el escritorio de mi usuario y no son enlaces simbólicos.

¿Alguna idea de qué puede estar pasando?

Comment: Esta línea chirría execvp(./home/pelu/Fundamentos, de, , g++-8 ...) "Fundamentos,de,," Como bien dices, hay espacios en blanco y eso puede provocar el error.

Comment: Lo sé, pero no entiendo de dónde viene, pues los archivos del proyecto no están ahí. Y los directorios de Debug y Release tampoco tienen nada que ver con ese.

Comment: Habría que ver las rutas que tienes en los archivos de configuración. Prueba no obstante a eliminar los espacios en blanco para asegurarte de que el error está ahí,y luego tocará mirar por qué usa esa ruta. Suerte!

Comment: Probé a cambiar la carpeta "Fundamentos de programación" por "FundamentosDeProgramación" en /home/pelu, y sigue entrando el input de "Fundamentos, de,, " a C::B. Sé que lo que voy a preguntar puede no tener sentido alguno, pero en algún momento de las pruebas para localizar el origen del error, bajé el proyecto que intento compilar de Google Drive, y en la ruta de Drive existe también una carpeta llamada "Fundamentos de Programación". ¿Sería posible por algún motivo disparatado que esto influya en el debug de C::B?

Comment: La verdad es que no sé qué es execvp, pero viendo este enlace: http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/exec.html necesita argumentos, y el primero de ellos debe de estar mal formado y la cadena la toma como varios argumentos diferentes. ¿Hay alguna línea en el código que haga uso de execvp?